# Why are libcpp.vector so slow?

Tags: cython

I'm making a few experimentations using Cython to determine whether I should use it to speed up some parts of my Django modules.
Since I'm using a lot of strings and lists of strings, I tried this:

```
from libcpp.string cimport string
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

def cython_test_string():
    cdef unsigned short int i = 0
    cdef string s
    # cdef vector[string] ls
    for i in range(10000):
        s.append('a')
        # ls.push_back(s)

def python_test_string():
    s = ''
    # ls = []
    for i in range(10000):
        s += 'a'
        # ls.append(s)
```

Of course, C++ strings are faster than Python objects, so we get these results (for 100 iterations):

- Cython : 0.0110609531403 seconds
- Python : 0.193608045578 seconds

But when we uncomment the four lines that deal with vector and list, we get this:

- Cython : 2.80126094818 seconds
- Python : 2.13021802902 seconds

Am I missing something, or are vectors of strings extremely slow?

Comment: I think this is because STL containers makes a copy. I.e. ls.push_back(s) makes a copy every time you insert a string. Also if you know vector size to be 10000 you can hint it as <code>cdef vector[string*] ls = vector[string*](10000)</code> (resising is also slow).  dont know time complexity of string::append bit if it is makeing copy this is bad also. Welcome aboard to ship of disapointed in C++ :) I think python's ls.append(s) doesn't make a copy, it just stores a pointer to PyObject, although i don't know exactly.

Comment: Surely you can speedup the cython version rewriting it without C++ and needless memory coping. However i found your example code to be focused on coping coping memory.

Comment: Thanks for these answers! After a lot of surprising slow tries, I decided to stay in the perfect world of pure Python :P